# postgis advanced (?) selection query

Tags: postgresql, postgis, self-join

The problem: I need to select, for each building in my table that has say at least 2 pharmacies and 2 education centers within a radius of 1km, all POIs (pharmacies, comercial centres, medical centers, education centers, police stations, fire stations) which are within 1km of the respective building. table structure->

building (id serial, name varchar )

poi_category(id serial, cname varchar) --cname being the category name of course

poi(id serial, name varchar, c_id integer)-- c_id is the FK referencing poi_category(id)

all coordinate columns are of type geometry not geography (let's call them geom)

here's the way i thought it should be done but i'm not sure it's even correct let alone the optimal solution to this problem

```
SELECT r.id_b, r.id_p
FROM (
     SELECT b.id AS id_b, p.id AS id_p, pc.id AS id_pc,pc.cname
     FROM building AS b, poi AS p, poi_category AS pc
     WHERE ST_DWithin(b.geom,p.geom, 1000) AND p.c_id=pc.id
     ) AS r,
     (
     SELECT * FROM r GROUP BY id_b
     ) AS r1

 HAVING  count (
                   SELECT *
                   FROM r, r1
                   WHERE r1.id_b=r.id_b AND r.id_pc='pharmacy'

                )>1
             AND
             count (
                   SELECT *
                   FROM r, r1
                   WHERE r1.id_b=r.id_b AND r.id_pc='ed. centre'

                )>1
```

Is this the way to go for what i need ? What solution would be better from a performance point of view? What about the most elegant solution?
I've also posted here :http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11445/postgis-advanced-selection-query

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution I elaborated. It's the fastest one I could find but it's still slow. Given the nature of the task I doubt it can be made faster...

```
WITH 
building AS (
  SELECT way, osm_id
  FROM osm_polygon
  WHERE tags @> hstore('building','yes')
  --ORDER BY 1 
  LIMIT 1000
),
pharmacy AS (
  SELECT way
  FROM osm_poi
  WHERE tags @> hstore('amenity','pharmacy') 
), 
school AS (
  SELECT way 
  FROM osm_poi
  WHERE tags @> hstore('amenity','school') 
)
SELECT ST_AsText(building.way) AS geom, building.osm_id AS label
FROM building
WHERE
  (SELECT count(*) > 1
   FROM pharmacy
   WHERE ST_DWithin(building.way,pharmacy.way,1000))
  AND
  (SELECT count(*) > 1
   FROM school
   WHERE ST_DWithin(building.way,school.way,1000))
```

Yours. S.